# Distance to point on circle as function of angle and initial distance

Tags: geometry

I have a circle with radius $r$ and a line coming from the center of that circle at a distance $L_0$ like this: 
[image]

then, I want to find the distance $L$ to a different point on this circle, measured by angle $\theta$ which goes clockwise, like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can calculate $L$ as a function of $\theta$ and $L$? I tried doing some trigonometry but was unsuccessful.

What about in the more general case where the initial point of $L_0$ is not perpendicular to the circle? For example, this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Law of Cosines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html) (which you might think of as a super-powered version of the Pythagorean Theorem, which allows you to work with triangles that are not right triangles).  It states that in any triangle with angles $a,b,c$ opposite sides of length $A,B,C$ (respectively), we have
$$ A^2 = B^2 + C^2 - 2AB \cos(a). $$
In your problem, we know the three sides, and so we get
$$ L^2 = r^2 + (r+L_0)^2 - 2r(r+L_0) \cos(\theta)
\implies \cos(\theta) = \frac{L^2 - r^2 - (r+L_0)^2}{2r(r+L_0)}.$$
Therefore, up to a choice of quadrant,
$$ \theta = \arccos\left( \frac{L^2 - r^2 - (r+L_0)^2}{2r(r+L_0)} \right). $$

Comment: That all makes sense, I actually was thinking of a more general case, which I added a diagram of in my question. I should probably submit a new question with just the more general diagram.

Comment: Look for triangles that will help you get the job done, and remember the various congruence relations.  If you know $\varphi$, $L$, and $L_0$, then the "side-angle-side" congruence relation indicates that you can find the third side of the triangle formed by $L$ and $L_0$ (e.g. using the Law of Sines).  If we call this side $A$, you can then consider the triangle with sides $A$, $r$, and $r$ and the angle $\theta$.  Using the Law of Cosines, you can find $\theta$.

Comment: But I don't know $L$ or $\phi$. All I know is $L_0$ and $\theta$. Is it even possible to calculate $L$ with this little information?

Comment: The segment $L$ is not uniquely determined by only $\theta$ and $L_0$.  If you fix one end of $L_0$ on the circle, but allow the other end to vary, it will trace out another circle.  Each point on that circle can be joined to a point on the original circle, giving a different possible segment $L$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$L^2=(L_0+r)^2+r^2-2r (L_0+r)\cos (\theta) $$

$$=L_0^2+4r(r+L_0)\sin^2 (\frac {\theta}{2})$$

Comment: To be fair, that's not really a hint. That's the answer.